# Can not copy data of HTML tags to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

For some reasons I am trying to change functionality of submit button. I am facing problem in copying data from HTML tags to JS. The alert generated by following code prints "Undefined" not the data inside tag.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input class="inputtext" id="email" name="email" type="text"></div>
    <input value="Submit" name="v4l" id="login" class="inputsubmit" type="button" onclick="myFunction();return false">

    <script>    
      function myFunction() {
        var TestVar =document.getElementsByClassName('login').value;
        alert(TestVar);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know it can be done by form but I need it this way.

Comment: Do you mean `getElementsByClassName("login")[0].value`?

Comment: Or even `getElementById("login").value`? (in your case, `login` is the id of the input)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why getElementsByClassName does not work for me? What does it return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/why-getelementsbyclassname-does-not-work-for-me-what-does-it-return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var TestVar = document.getElementById('email').value
alert(TestVar);
```

this will get value of text field

Answer (score 2):

```
getElementsByClassName
          ^
```

See that `s`? Elements is **plural**. `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` (which is like an `Array`).

You have to either pick an index from it (`foo[0]`) or loop over it to get the values.

---

That said, you don't actually have any elements that are a member of the `login` class, so it is going to return a Node List of zero length.

You do have an element with `id="login"`, so maybe you should use `getElementById` instead.

---

There doesn't seem much point in reading the value from an element that you've hard coded the value for. You might actually want to be using `document.getElementById('email')`